# Comparing Models in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I currently have two models, Model A and Model B. Within Model A is a column called `modules`, and within Model B is a column called `new Modules`.

What i want to do is compare the values in `new Modules` column against the values in the `modules` column in Model A, and return back a list of any values in the `new Modules` column that didn't match any value in the `modules` column

I'm unable to create a query to do what i want, and was wondering would anyone know how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
modules_a = ModelA.objects.values_list('modules', flat=True).distinct()
modules_b = ModelB.objects.values_list('new_modules', flat=True).distinct()
diff = [i for i in module_b if i not in modules_a]
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#values-list